# Extracting numbers (in decimal and </> form) from strings in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which a column (the result variable) contains data in both numeric and character form `[e.g. positive, negative, <0.1, 600, >1000 etc]`.

I want to extract only the numeric data in this column `(i.e. <0.1, 600, >1000)`. Ideally without the use of any external packages.

I tried  the following:

```
x<-gsub('\\D','', x)
```

But it removes the decimals or less than/more than sign (`e.g. 1.56 became 156, <1.0 became 10`)

I then tried the following:

```
x<-as.numeric(gsub("(\\D)\\.","", x))
```

This time round it keeps the decimal but coerced other values such as `<0.1, >100` to become NAs instead.

So my question is, is there any way I can modify the function such that it will keep values containing the '<' or '>" as it is without replacement.

Meaning from

```
x = c("negative","positive","1.22","<1.0",">200") 
I will be able to get back
x = c("","","1.22","<1.0",">200)
```

I would really appreciate if someone can teach me how to resolve this issue thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need this?

```
> gsub("[^0-9.<>]", "", x)
[1] ""     ""     "1.22" "<1.0" ">200"
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I needed, along with removing the as.numeric from function helped solved my problem!

Comment: In `[]` there is no need to escape: `gsub("[^0-9.<>]", "", x)` will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you ? Using grep we can find which all items of the vectors contains numbers, then using value=TRUE will give us those items present. Another way could be using grepl to get logical output for the match. Also in your case `\\D` would not work as it is match to all non digits including dot, greater than signs.

```
grep('\\d+', x, value=TRUE)
```

would yield : `[1] "1.22" "<1.0" ">200"`

```
grepl('\\d+', x)
```

would yield: `[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE`

You may also try `gsub` using:

```
> gsub('[a-zA-Z]+', '', x)
[1] ""     ""     "1.22" "<1.0" ">200"
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! I tried that but I received an error message:


Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, x value = c("1270", "< 1.0                                                         ",  : 
  replacement has 5719 rows, data has 14692

Comment: @Jin you need to use x as as column vector, so in your case , if you have a dataframe as df and column name as col then `gsub('[a-zA-Z]+', '', df$col)`. Please put a sample of your dataframe to understand your problem more.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(x, "[A-Za-z]+")
#[1] ""     ""     "1.22" "<1.0" ">200"
```

Answer (score 0):

What, what about something like this? Find that elements that do not match your conditions and set them to an empty string.

```r
x <- x[grep('[a-zA-Z]', x)] <- ""
```